# What is the good RMSE (root-mean-square-error) value range to justify the efficiency of multivariate linear regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm a new bee in ML domain. Following some simple ML techniques, I build a multivariate linear regression-based ML model for predicting the computation resource usage for a system. So, when I perform the test, considering my ML model, I got the RMSE value less than 7 (approx. ~ 6.632). So, I'm a bit curious to know that, is this value is acceptable for the scientific community? Or the value is too high? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: RMSE acts as a sort of "average magnitude of error", effectively telling you the average size of regression errors. You will have to decide if what is, in effect, an average error size of 6.632 is OK for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining how the RMSE is actually acting...I really appreciate that....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a software development question as defined in the [help]. Theoretical ML questions might be more at home on [stats.se].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me give you two examples having the same RMSE value:

- I'm trying to predict renting price for an apartment with renting price typically lying in range 500$-1000$. An RMSE value of 15$ could be argued to be a very low RMS error and the line of best fit would satisfy my needs.
- I'm trying to predict the price of my next family dinner, with prices ranging typically between 10$-25$. The same RMSE value of 15$ could be deemed poor and the line of best fit would probably not be satisfiable.

The interpretation of many scores in regression problems (i.e. RMSE, MAE, MSE) all depends on the domain of your problem, and what you would find acceptable. You can't really compare RMSE scores unless its derived from the same regression problem.

Answer (score 3):

Deciding whether a RMSE score is reliable or not is a function of the range of the target variable, a larger range can justify a larger RMSE score. That having said, one may want to check for outliers, since these will largely affect your RMSE despite having seemingly good fit.