# What's the range of RMSE? Is there a maximum value?

Tags: machine-learning, model, regression, data-science, metrics

What is the range of RMSE during a evaluation model? I know that close to 0 is better, but tis there a maximum value for this? I can't find the answer... If I have a 52 RMSE how can I say if it's a good result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348495/what-is-the-good-rmse-root-mean-square-error-value-range-to-justify-the-effici

Comment: For [tag:machine-learning], questions should focus on implementation, theory questions are usually better in different communities (e.g. stats stackexchange). See also: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).